# How to add github private repo to my Helm environment

Tags: github, kubernetes-helm

I have a `github` private repo ( containing valid `index.yaml` file) and I want to add it to my local `helm` environment without using the github **token** but I can use my gihub credentials.I have tried something like

```
helm repo add <reponame> --username <username> --password xxxx https://<username>.github.io/reponame
```

**Error Message**

> Error: Looks like "https://username.github.io/reponame" is not
>   a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Failed to fetch
>   https://username.github.io/reponame/index.yaml : 404 Not Found

But the above command worked with public repo even without passing the credentials of my github account
I have also tried with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/reponame/branch raw url but the error  still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https://<username>.github.io/reponame` looks like a [GitHub page URL](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites), which you can compare with [fluxcd/helm-operator-get-started issue 28](https://github.com/fluxcd/helm-operator-get-started/issues/28).
It points out to a [valid chart side](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux/wiki/MoveToFluxCD#2019-07-10-flux-has-moved-house)

Its repository includes the [relevant yaml files](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux/tree/master/chart/flux).

Following "[Using a private github repo as helm chart repo (https access)](https://medium.com/hackernoon/using-a-private-github-repo-as-helm-chart-repo-https-access-95629b2af27c)", using a token seems to be mandatory.
It certainly is if you have 2FA activated.

The [OP Pycoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500530/pycoder) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59588120/how-to-add-github-private-repo-to-my-helm-environment/59603433#comment105411070_59603433):

> I can:
>
> - either pass the personal access token in URL
>     '`https://<token>@raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<reponame>/master/`',
> - or pass the token in password flag
>     `helm add repo --username <username> --password <token> url`.

Comment: I tried but not even worked for github public repository. I am getting error with `Error: Looks like "https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Failed to fetch https://github.com/<username>/<repo name>/index.yaml : 404 Not Found`.

Comment: @Pycoder I have rewritten the answer. Do you have 2FA (2 factor authentication) activated on your GitHub account?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information. I don't have a 2FA activated in my GitHub account. I know that I can add the GitHub private repo ( It should have a valid index.yaml ) into my Helm environment by using Personal Access Token. But my question is, Is it possible to do the same thing with GitHub username and Password ( without using the GitHub Personal Access Token ).

Comment: @Pycoder I understand and agree with your question. So far, I have only seen that kind of URL used with a token.

Comment: Yup I can either pass the personal access token in URL `'https://<token>@raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<reponame>/master/'` or can also pass the token in password flag `helm add repo --username <username> --password <token> url. Both will work.

Comment: @Pycoder OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.